# String column to multiple columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns:

```
A     B     C

a1.   b1.   r: 200
            l: 350
            t:600

a2    b2.   

a3    b3.   r: 400
            t: 500
```

Now I want to break column C(whose each entry is separated by \n) into multiple column like this:

```
A.  B.  r.   l.   t 
a1  b1  200. 350. 600
a2  b2
a3. b3. 400.      500
```

I tried few techniques but can't make it. I tried to use df.apply but not able to fix NA columns.
Is there a way to cleanly achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your multi index is in the pattern of `a1,b1` , `a2,b2`.....`an,bn`?...I mean it is not like this `a1,b3`

Comment: it's not multi index. It is two columns A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using a `regex` with `str.split`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=[['a1', 'b1', 'r: 200\n l: 350\n t:600'], ['a2', 'b2', ''], ['a3', 'b3', 'r:400\n t:500']])
splitted = df.C.str.split('([r,l,t]{1}?):\s?(\d+)\n?\s?')
filtered = splitted.apply(lambda lst: list(filter(None, lst)))
numerical_values = filtered.apply(lambda lst: pd.Series(index=lst[0::2], data=lst[1::2], dtype=float))
df.join(numerical_values)
```

Comment: Actually this will not work. As sometime column C may contain only R and T. In that case it will assign the value wrongly. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question.

Comment: @user15350930 My bad, I had copied your data incorrectly. I have updated my answer.